# Fetch records with date range as filter from column with date datatype in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table in oracle which is having a column named "created_at" with timestamp as datatype and current_timestamp as default value and the column is  not nullable as well. Later, this column needed to be modified to datatype = date with today's date as default value and the column remained "NOT NULL" also. I've tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE abc.xyz
MODIFY "CREATED_AT" DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL;
```

Following is the filter I applied in my view file:

```
 'filter' => DateRangePicker::widget([
                'name' => 'daterange',
                'startAttribute' => 'report_date_from',
                'endAttribute' => 'report_date_to',
                'presetDropdown'=>false,
                'hideInput'=>true,
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Select date ...',
                ],
            ])
```

And following is the query parameter I've passed to search function in my search model class:

```
$query
        ->andFilterWhere(['between','CREATED_AT', $this->start_date, $this->end_date])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'NAME', $this->NAME])
...
```

Following is the error being encountered:

```
Getting unknown property: frontend\models\SearchModel::start_date
```

Is there any issue with filter that is being implemented?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! But I'm not working on 12c Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it by removing $this keyword:

```
    $query
        ->andFilterWhere(['between','CREATED_AT', $start_date, $end_date])
```

As $start_date and $end_date are the local variables and not database columns. :D
There was nothing wrong in the flow to fetch data by date range filter. My goodness!